# How can I set the value of the StaticResource to a DynamicResource?

Tags: wpf

I am coding a custom control and I want to make an animation to set the width of the control to the `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}`

However, WPF threw an exception that 'Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads'.

I found a solution in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9336022f-badb-4b40-a86c-a50ab1a64ba5/quotcannot-freeze-this-storyboard-timeline-tree-for-use-across-threadsquot?forum=wpf by using a StaticResource.

And then I wrote these codes soon:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <system:Double x:Key="VerticalScrollBarWidthKey"></system:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But I found that I can't set the StaticResource `VerticalScrollBarWidthKey` to the value of `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}`

How can I solve this? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: A `StaticResource` only looks up the referenced resource once, so you might as well set the value to `{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}`. if you require the value to be dynamic, you'd better implement the `Storyboard` programmatically.

Comment: @mm8 No, I don't want the value to be dynamic, but just set the StaticResource value equal the current value of the DynamicResource yet. In addition, the {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey} will almost never change in the same computer.

Comment: So what is your current issue? Can't you just remove the `DynamicResource` part?

Comment: @mm8 Different computer has a different value of the SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey, I don't need the DynamicResource at all, but just get its value and set the value to the StaticResource yet.

Comment: @mm8 I mean not binding the StaticResource to the DynamicResource, but just set the value of the StaticResource equal the current value of the DynamicResource. I don't need binding it or check if it is the same or not because VerticalScrollBarWidthKey will not change unless the user changes the resolution ratio of the screen.